# annoying Session overwriting

Tags: php, session

I'm  making a multi language website and i decided to use sessions to remember the current language , overall it works as its supposed to , but there is one bug that i can't fix .
1) i load the page and it displays properly in Bulgaria 
2) i add '&lang=en' to test if its working properly , and it does 
3) when i remove the '&lang=en' and its back to Bulgarian when its not supposed to its supposed to stay in English

here is what is in the header of the page

```
   if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
    $lang = htmlspecialchars($_GET['lang']);
lang($lang);
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['slang'])){
    lang('bg');
}else {
    lang($_SESSION['slang']);
}
```

and here is my function that handles the language switching

```
function lang($lang=''){

        if($lang=='bg'){
            $_SESSION['slang'] = 'bg' ;
            include_once('./includes/bulgarian.php');
        }
        if ($lang == 'en'){
            $_SESSION['slang'] = 'en' ;
            include_once('./includes/english.php');
        }else {
            $_SESSION['slang'] = 'bg' ;
            include_once('./includes/bulgarian.php');
        }

}
```

if someone can explain me why this is happening and how i can fix it it would be great 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're calling `session_start` on each page. I tried it on my computer, and got your results without the session_start. When I added it, it worked  as desired.

You can try using `echo session_id();` to see if the session is started on any page

Comment: yup , i forgot that i must start a session >_> excuse me

Answer (score 2):

Judging from what you wrote the code should work you should check if $_SESSION actually gets across pages.

Are you using: [session_start();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the Gnu's gettext spec if I were you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext

Comment: i might use that in future projects ! thanks for pointing it out !

Answer (score 0):

Browser cache? Can you clear all saved info in the browser and then try?

Answer (score 0):

Please call `session_start()` to load your session.